# Validates_length_of with variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use rails-settings-cached to set a few of the variables - password minimum and password maximum.

When I try to incorporate these into `validates_length_of` I get the following error message:
`:minimum must be a nonnegative Integer or Infinity`

The code:
`validates_length_of :password, :minimum => lambda{Setting.password_min}, :maximum => lambda{Setting.password_max}, :if => :should_validate_password?`

I know the variables are set because when I go into `rails console` the variables are set:

```
 2.0.0-p353 :009 > Setting.password_max
 => "14" 
 2.0.0-p353 :010 > Setting.password_min
 => "6"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Probably your Setting model reading values after Rails models loaded. So it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting strings to integers using to_i. I.e.

```
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => lambda{Setting.password_min.to_i}, :maximum => lambda{Setting.password_max.to_i}, :if => :should_validate_password?
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using lambdas?

The error you are getting is because the :minimum option must take an Integer or Infinity value. You are providing it with functions created by lambda.

Why can't you use:

```
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => Setting.password_min, ...
```

Comment: If I remove the lambsas I get the same thing. There is no difference in the error either.

Answer (score 0):

The variables being saved in a different part of the application were not getting saved as numbers. I have fixed that and reset the variables and this fixed the issue.